# SharePoint Calculated Column Multi Conditional Formula

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, error, calculated-column-formula, date-time

I have a Final Submission Due Date calculated column.

I am trying to create a condition to where if another column (Yes/No Boolean) is checked add a certain value, if not use the original value.

I receive this error:

> The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported.

My formula:

```
=IF([Submit to] = True, 
    IF(ISBLANK([Initial Submission Due Date],
        "",([Initial Submission Due Date]+5)
        )
    )
    ),
    IF([Submit to] = False,
    IF(ISBLANK([Initial Submission Due Date],
        "", ([Initial Submission Due Date])
        )
        )
        )
```

I have also tried a simpler formula but it yields the same result

```
=IF([Submit to] = TRUE, IF(ISBLANK([Initial Submission Due Date],"",([Initial Submission Due Date]+ 5)), [Initial Submission Due Date]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check true/false value of Yes/No column directly by referring column name as given in below example.

Try using formula in below format for your calculated column:

```
=IF([Submit to], IF(ISBLANK([Initial Submission Due Date]),"",[Initial Submission Due Date]+5), [Initial Submission Due Date])
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).

Comment: Ganesh saves the day!